# Android inserting multiple single item into a ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> from HashMap<String, String>

Tags: android, string, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to insert multiple single item into an ArrayList> 
Here is my code:

```
 public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alarmClocks = new ArrayList<>();
    public void q1() {
            int[] multipleHours = {9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18}; //store here the hours for every alarm you want to set
            int[] multipleMinutes = {45, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 45}; //store here the minutes
            String[] multipleDestinations = {"Departure", "Quezon Heritage House", "Art In Island", "Quezon City Experience", "Quezon Memorial", " Destination 5", "Destination 6"}; //same thing for destinations
            String[] multipleReminders = {"You need to go to Destination 1", "Timeout, Go to next destination", "Timeout, Go to next destination", "Timeout, Go to next destination", "Timeout, Go to next destination", "Timeout, Go to next destination", "Package Ended!"}; //and reminders
            HashMap<String, String> alarm = new HashMap<>();
            alarm.put(ApplicationConstants.HOUR, String.valueOf(multipleHours));
            alarm.put(ApplicationConstants.MINUTE, String.valueOf(multipleMinutes));
            alarm.put(ApplicationConstants.REMINDER, String.valueOf(multipleReminders));
            alarm.put(ApplicationConstants.DESTINATION, String.valueOf(multipleDestinations));
    alarmClocks.add(alarm);

        }
```

The insertion should be like this:

Item 1: 9 - 45 - Departure - You need to go to destination 1

Item 2: 11 - 0 - Quezon Heritage House - Timeout, Go to next destination.

My problem is the codes includes all of the item in the array

Error prompts up like this:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "[9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<multipleHours.length;i++){
HashMap<String, String> alarm = new HashMap<>();
        alarm.put(ApplicationConstants.HOUR, String.valueOf(multipleHours[i]));
        alarm.put(ApplicationConstants.MINUTE, String.valueOf(multipleMinutes[i]));
        alarm.put(ApplicationConstants.REMINDER, String.valueOf(multipleReminders[i]));
        alarm.put(ApplicationConstants.DESTINATION, String.valueOf(multipleDestinations[i]));
alarmClocks.add(alarm);
}
```

but remember all the array length should be same else it will give indexoutofbound error.

Comment: i was gonna answer it (to late) , but this bro is right use for loop

Comment: I'm sorry about the lack of details about the problem, but i need the code to put into the onClick.

Comment: on which view you want the onclick?